# What are good books for learning grammar ( BNF )?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, books

I'm taking a basic course on programming language theory, and we're covering context-free grammar (BNF). Personally, I'm really interested in how to design syntax for a programming language. I'm planning to write a simple compiler for my graduate project, so what books are good for this area? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: Virtual vote to close as exact duplicate of http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/books-on-automata-theory-for-self-study

Comment: I don't see it as an identical question @Kaveh. Maybe the *answers* would end up being the same, but the question you linked to seems more logic-directed, whereas this seems more directed toward practical implementation. For example, if @Chan is interested in implementing something in a "hot topic," he could look at the TOOLS section of the [Visibly Pushdown Languages](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~madhu/vpa/) page.

Comment: @Aaron Sterling: Excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For just learning about BNF grammars, a good reference is [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201441241).

However, since you mentioned its with the interest of developing a compiler, the [dragon book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201100886) is probably the best reference possible.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend the [ANTLR Reference](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference). It explains many issues with language parsing (without the depth of the Dragon Book, though) and introduces you to a powerful (free) tool, namely a compiler generator. For both reasons, it might be a good starting point for your studies.