# Are there any books containing collections of automata problems?

Tags: dfa, books

You can find specialized books consisting entirely or problems from particular math domains (e.g. linear algebra, polynomials, combinatorics), but I've yet to find such a book for automata of any kind.

Comment: The exercises in Hopcroft & Ullman first edition, and possibly also the earlier FLRA book by them (available online at http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1096945)?

Comment: I would like such a book, pretty sure there isn't one though.  If we were to build one as a community, Shiva Kintali's site TrueShelf would be a good place to collect such problems.  http://www.trueshelf.com/all/

Comment: Similar question: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/books-on-automata-theory-for-self-study

Comment: The book "Elements of Automata Theory" by Sakarovitch covers Automata Theory deeply. However, he uses a different notation compared to TCS-oriented texts. Once you got over this, its a pretty good book.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of indirectly, this book is about research level automata problems:

http://www.amazon.ca/Automatic-Sequences-Theory-Applications-Generalizations/dp/0521823323

An automatic sequence is essentially a set of strings which can be computed by a DFA.